# Ubuntu 18.04 Can't use gcc - fopenmp option

Tags: gcc

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and the command `gcc openmp1.c -o openmp1 –fopenmp` returns this error:

```
gcc: error: –fopenmp: no such file or directory
```

My gcc version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
```

Comment: I added an answer since this question is currently clogging up the new questions. but @steeldriver feel free to answer as well and I'll remove mine.

Comment: @tatsu no that's all good

Answer (score 2):

This is a copy-paste error :  `–fopenmp` has a unicode dash in place of a regular ASCII dash. use this instead :

```
gcc -fopenmp
```